# I Want to Insert a Token Item on Jquery tokenInput

Tags: jquery, tokenize, jquery-tokeninput

In jQuery Plugin: Tokenizing Autocomplete Text Entry, we have:

```
$("#tokenize").tokenInput("php-example.php?a=1&b=2", {
        hintText: "Type in the names of your favorite TV shows",
        noResultsText: "No results",
        searchingText: "Searching..."
});
```

how can I use the function "insert_token" to add new intes to the list, and how can I pre-populate the list?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

**Just add**

```
$("#input").tokenInput("add", {id: 1, name: 'John Dore'})
```

Comment: Where i have to add this ?

Answer (score 2):

I have made a modification that allows you to add tokens to the list programmatically. Insert the following under the add_token function:

```
// Add a token to the token list based on javascript invocation
arguments.callee.add_token_api = function (id, name) {
    var this_token = insert_token(id, name);

    // Save this token id
    var id_string = id + ","
    hidden_input.val(hidden_input.val() + id_string);

    token_count++;

    if(settings.tokenLimit != null && settings.tokenLimit >= token_count) {
        input_box.hide();
        hide_dropdown();
    }
}
```

So afterwards you can add an item by using

```
$.TokenList.add_token_api(19, "Alabama Joachim")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a new user who can not post comment, so forgive me writing here.

@Alexandros Marinos: Your solution is good only when there is only one tokeninput element on page? Can we have another syntax such as these?

$("#my_tokeninput_element_1").tokenInput.add_token(19, "Alabama");

$("#my_tokeninput_element_2").tokenInput.add_token(29, "Washington");